# Hibernate ManyToMany Association?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two tables in Hibernate with Spring Boot: "Game" and "Category"

A Game has multiple Categories and Categories can have multiple Games. Now I need a table between "Game" and "Category" to store both Primary Keys from the tables as Foreign Keys.

I called the table "Game2Categorie".

Now my question is how the 3 classes should look like in Java?

Game has gid as PK. 
Category has cid as PK. 
Game2Categorie should only have gid and cid from above as FKs.

Can someone show me how to create those three classes?

Comment: You're doing it wrong: you should start by designing your domain that makes sense in your application and then use JPA/Hibernate to "squeeze" it into a database.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create classes for `Game` and `Category` as these are your only entities. I would suggest to read the Hibernate doc from the beginning to understand the concept of entities first.

You then define your relation with `@ManyToMany`. Hibernate will then use a third table for representing this relation on the database side. You can define the name of that table via `@JoinTable`.

[This tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/) explains it in detail.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at it. Thank you very much! So the "third" table will be created automatically in my database, correct?

Comment: Yes, if you use your entity model to generate the database, e. g. with `hbm2dll` or [Liquibase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki), the third table will be created automatically alongside your entity tables.

Comment: I tested it out and it worked. In Phpmyadmin I have now the third table as well. But my question is if it is correct that it contains 2 primary keys (gameid and categoryid) and 1 FK on categoryid. If I look at the relations it says I have 2 FKs. Is that correct and what I wanted? I though I only need FKs in such a "third" table?

Comment: Did you specify the `@ManyToMany` relation on both entities? If you can't access the relation in both directions, Hibernate probably doesn't place FK indexes on both directions accordingly.